# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'select'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am trying to rewrite this SQL query into Pyspark

```
SELECT b.BrandId,a.PaymentIdentifier,a.PaymentName
FROM checkpaymentdetailmca a
INNER JOIN dimension b
ON a.Brand = b.Brand
AND a.StoreNumber = b.Storenumber
```

Here is my attempt at writing this in pyspark:

```
df = spark.read.parquet('abfss://container_name@xyz.dfs.core.windows.net/folder_name/checkpaymentdetailmca/parquet/**/*')

df1= spark.read.parquet('abfss://container_name@xyz.dfs.core.windows.net/folder_name/dimension//parquet/**/*')

df_final = df.join(df1,df['sbr_brand']==df1['brand'])\
         &(df1,df['sbr_number']==df1['store_number'])\
        .select(df['payment_number','payment_type_name','payment_identifier'],df1['brand_id'])
display(df_final)
```

Here is the types of error I get:

1. 'tuple' object has no attribute 'select'
2. 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: Why not use Spark SQL?

Comment: Try this `df_final = df.join(df1, (df['sbr_brand']==df1['brand']) & (df['sbr_number']==df1['store_number']))\
.select('payment_number','payment_type_name','payment_identifier', 'brand_id')`